# How to create a nested array in SASS, not SCSS

Tags: sass

So I  know that you can make an array in ***SCSS*** just by this code:

```scss
$clr: (
  prim: (
    step1: #8ef99e,
    step2: #76f789,
    step3: #5ef674,
    step4: #46f460,
    step5: #2ef34b,
    step6: #0de12c,
    step7: #0cc927,
    step8: #0ab123,
    step9: #09991e,
    step10: #078119,
    step11: #066814
  ), 
  light: (
    step1: #ffffff,
    step2: #f7f7f7,
    step3: #f0f0f0,
    step4: #e8e8e8,
    step5: #e0e0e0,
    step6: #d9d9d9
  )
)
```

but that's only if you're coding in ***.scss***, so how can I make this in ***SASS***?
I tried doing this:

```scss
$clr: 
  prim: 
    step1: #8ef99e,
    step2: #76f789,
    step3: #5ef674,
    step4: #46f460,
    step5: #2ef34b,
    step6: #0de12c,
    step7: #0cc927,
    step8: #0ab123,
    step9: #09991e,
    step10: #078119,
    step11: #066814
  light: 
    step1: #ffffff,
    step2: #f7f7f7,
    step3: #f0f0f0,
    step4: #e8e8e8,
    step5: #e0e0e0,
    step6: #d9d9d9
```

but I'm getting an error saying

```
Error: Expected expression.
  |
1 | $clr: 
  |      ^
  |
```

Did I make a mistake or is it really unavailable for ***.sass*** to make this kind of array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SASS, you need to write maps on a single line:

```
$clr: (prim: (step1: #8ef99e, step2: #76f789, step3: #5ef674, step4: #46f460, step5: #2ef34b, step6: #0de12c, step7: #0cc927, step8: #0ab123, step9: #09991e, step10: #078119, step11: #066814), light: (step1: #ffffff, step2: #f7f7f7, step3: #f0f0f0, step4: #e8e8e8, step5: #e0e0e0, step6: #d9d9d9))
```